# Plone call python function from login_next script

Tags: python, plone, zope

I have my Plone instance setup. I am trying to call custom python script function from my login_next script.

How would I do that ?

say for eg:

Custom_print.py

```
def disp():
   return 'Hello world'
```

How would I call this disp() inside my login_next script ?

Answer (score 1):

So this Custom_print.py is in a skins directory that is available in portal_skins and is used in the default skin?  In other words: visiting http://your-plone-site/Custom_print returns the string 'Hello world'?

Then you can customize the login_next script (in the custom map of portal_skins or in your own skin on the file system) and call `context.Custom_print()` there.

Answer (score 1):

it depends on where did you put that script:

- if you have that script in a skin directory you will have to use Acquisition (as maurits says): `context.Custom_print()` . Just be aware of [Acquisition's pitfalls](http://docs.zope.org/zope2/zdgbook/Acquisition.html).
- if it's filesystem module you will just "use it" like this: 
  `import mymodule; mymodule.Custom_print()`

Comment: No, you cannot just 'use it' by importing. The login_next script runs under certain restrictions, and only if the filesystem module is on the module whitelist can you import it.

Comment: eheh, you are right...you have to enable it in allowed modules with this code: http://wiki.zope.org/zope2/HowToAddModulesToRestrictedCode

Answer (score 1):

In the old Zope2/CMF portal_skins world, a portal_skins/*/foo.py object is treated *like a method itself*.  IOW, there's no need to wrap it's contents with a `def func_name()` because the skin object will be "called" just by traversing to it with `context.foo()`.  No importing or any of the other normal python stuff.

While we're trying to move away from this stuff as quickly as we can and back to more pythonic sanity, login_next is still a portal_skins script, so using a portal_skins script for what you're trying to do is appropriate.  So your login_next script can just do `return "Hello World"` yourself.